# C#, Unity3D and Google Fusion Tables - Getting 411 response

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-fusion-tables

I am doing a system that imports live data from Fusion tables.

I am using C# in Unity3D so, I don't have the WebRequest from .NET framework.

However, Unity3D has WWW and WWWForm and I am trying to use those to query Fusion Tables.
I already have the Authentication Token but the SQL injection API is returning a 411 page requesting Content-Length.

I already added that to the headers, but still, no change...

Bellow i am posting the code for the Query Test, it assumes valid authentication in Fusion Tables

```
public string Execute(string query) {

    string result;

    var url_fusion_tables = "https://tables.googlelabs.com/api/query/?";

    WWWForm postdata = new WWWForm();

    System.Collections.Hashtable headers = postdata.headers;

    headers["Method"] = "POST";
    headers["Content-Type"] = "applicaton/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    string header_token = string.Format("GoogleLogin auth = {0}", token);
    headers["Authorization"] = header_token;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("sql=");
    sb.Append(WWW.EscapeURL("SHOW TABLES"));

    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    headers["Content-Length"] = data.Length;

    WWW reqClient = new WWW(url_fusion_tables, data, headers);

    StartCoroutine(WaitForQuery(reqClient));

    return null;

}

IEnumerator WaitForQuery(WWW www) {

    yield return www;

    if (www.error == null) {

        //Debug.Log("Success");
        Debug.Log("Received :: " + www.text);


    } else {
        Debug.Log("Query WWW error : "+ www.error);
    }
}
```

Hope anyone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Due to Kathryn's help i have edited the Execute function to the following:

```
    public void Execute(string query) {
    //in query : SHOW TABLES

    var sql = string.Format("sql={0}", WWW.EscapeURL(query));
    var url_fusion_tables = "https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?";

    WWWForm postdata = new WWWForm();


    System.Collections.Hashtable headers = postdata.headers;

    headers["AllowAutoRedirect"] = true;
    headers["AllowWriteStreamBuffering "] = true;
    headers["Method"] = "GET";
    headers["Content-Type"] = "applicaton/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    string header_token = string.Format("GoogleLogin auth = {0}", token);
    headers["Authorization"] = header_token;

    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sql);
    headers["Content-Length"] = data.Length;

    WWW reqClient = new WWW(url_fusion_tables, data, headers);

    StartCoroutine(WaitForQuery(reqClient));

}
```

I'm still receiving 411 response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved the problem...

As i said before, the 411 was returned because the token string i passed to the authentication header had a *new line* tag in it, so the server would interpret that as the end of the Header on the POST. Removing the \n at the end of the string results in a good request.

The next problem was due to a bad query, my mistake on putting the wrong Table ID.

Thanks Kathryn for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following URL instead for GET requests (SHOW TABLES can be sent via GET):

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=[query]

For POST requests, use the same URL...

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query

...and send sql=[query] in the body.

Also make sure to URL encode the query in both cases.

Comment: Thank you for the reply... I tried that but it still gives me the 411 response... Any other ideas?

Comment: After searching some more i found out that it is possible for my token string to have a \n newline flag at the end. So i removed the last byte from the string. This could have made the server think the header is over and would not read the Content-length. Now i get a 500 error from Fusion Tables saying "Unable to execute query (which appears to be correct) at this time. Please retry" is this fixable?